# How do I automatically clear output in MySQL workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, workbench

I'm trying to find the preference settings to have the output clear every time my statement or set of statements are executed. I would prefer this option instead of right clicking and clearing the output every time I want to. I just can't find it and I'm not sure it exists as an option.

Answer (score 3):

There's no such thing like auto-clearing. If you want that implemented file a feature request in the MySQL bug system (http://bugs.mysql.com).